# Does anyone know how to fix the Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1 error for magento connect

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, web-deployment, magento-1.9

I am trying to install a theme for my Magento web application.

When I go to Magento Connect and put in the encryption key for the theme and try to install I get an

```
"community/Buzzthemes_Watch_Store_Template: Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1" error. After I browsed through some other resources I was able to learn that I had to uncomment the line 
 //$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, ‘TLSv1′); that was located in downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
```

However it seems as though everyone can find that line of code except for me. I have searched up and down for that line of code. Could someone please assist me in finding that line of code or telling me after what line should I add that code to. I would greatly appreciate the assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First method works for from the link below

```
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73861/solution-to-magento-downloader-1-9-2-unknown-cipher-list
```

Here , it explains to comment the code in line 377 in downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php